# pandas updating column value using isin and loc

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to update column in data frame one same as here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768657/replace-column-values-based-on-another-dataframe-python-pandas-better-way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wnjx.png). However i am not able to do so -

```
df = pd.read_csv('Analyzed_test.csv')
df['rule_prediction'] = " " # created a column
a1 = pd.read_csv('D:\Junk\ML\\files\\Analyzed_rule1.csv')
a2 = pd.read_csv('D:\Junk\ML\\files\\Analyzed_rule2.csv')
a3 = pd.read_csv('D:\Junk\ML\\files\\Analyzed_rule3.csv')
a4 = pd.read_csv('D:\Junk\ML\\files\\Analyzed_rule4.csv')

df.loc[df.ID.isin(a1.ID), ['rule_prediction']] = a1[['rule_prediction']]
df.loc[df.ID.isin(a2.ID), ['rule_prediction']] = a2[['rule_prediction']]
df.loc[df.ID.isin(a3.ID), ['rule_prediction']] = a3[['rule_prediction']]
df.loc[df.ID.isin(a4.ID), ['rule_prediction']] = a4[['rule_prediction']]

#print t.count
#print self.df.head()
df.to_csv('D:\Junk\ML\\files\\output.csv')
```

When i open output.csv i see no values populated.

Columns in Analyzed_rule[1-4].csv 
[dataframe in Analyzed_rule1.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wnjx.png)

The one i want to update is - 
Analyzed_test.csv to output.csv based on ID columns matched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You question looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)... Can you post a sample data set, short explanation about what do you want to change/update and a desired resulting data set?

Comment: ID |s rule_prediction
LP001153 N
LP001361 N
LP001599 Y
LP001652 N
LP001867 Y
LP001886 Y
LP002042 Y
LP002069 N
LP002183 Y
LP002412 Y
LP002415 N
LP002482 Y
LP002747 N
LP002858 N
LP002867 Y
LP002901 N

Comment: Could you [post it in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40114807/edit)?

Comment: Added.. Image link.

Comment: Pleas read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)