# Replace multiple column values in one dataframe by values of another dataframe subjected to a common key column

Tags: pandas, geopandas

I want to update the values in a GeoPanda dataframe from another GeoPanda dataframe for select columns. Both of them will have a common key called 'geometry.'

For example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["X",1,1,0],
              ["Y",0,1,0],
              ["Z",0,0,0],
              ["Y",0,0,0]],columns=["geometry","Nonprofit","Business", "Education"])    

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Y",1,1],
              ["Z",1,1]],columns=["geometry","Non", "Edu"])
```

[image]

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631906/9801811) I did the following steps:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('geometry')
df2 = df2.set_index('geometry')

list_1 = ['Nonprofit', 'Education']
list_2 = ['Non', 'Edu']

df1[list_1].update(df2[list_2])
```

This results in the wrong results without any warning. How can I fix this?

[image]

Notes:

Updating one column at a time (df1['Nonprofit'].update(df2['Non'])) will produce the correct result.

geometry Linestring from GeoPandas replaced by a character for simplicity.

Comment: Check your pandas version

Comment: I'm using pandas version '1.0.3'. Thanks

Comment: Then it is because you does not use current version of pandas. The answer in the link says warning occurs when using current version of pandas.

Comment: I think the issue is related to multiple columns labels passed in a list. When I used df1['Nonprofit'].update(df2['Non']) I got the correct answer. I am have issues when I pass the list for column names in df1[list_1].update(df2[list_2]). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataFrame.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) only updates columns with the same name!

Accordingly, one solution would be to first rename the columns in `df2` to match those in `df1`.

Note that when calling `update()`, there is no need to specify the target columns in `df1`: *all* common columns will be updated. If required, you can specify *which* columns you want from `df2` by using column indexing.

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Non': 'Nonprofit', 'Edu': 'Education'})
df1.update(df2)  

# optionally restrict columns:
# df1.update(df2['Nonprofit'])  

# alternative short version, leaving df2 untouched
df1.update(df2.rename(columns={'Non': 'Nonprofit', 'Edu': 'Education'}))
```

gives

```
          Nonprofit  Business  Education
geometry                                
X               1.0         1        0.0
Y               1.0         1        1.0
Z               1.0         0        1.0
Y               1.0         0        1.0
```

The reason your "single column" approach works is that there you're implicitly using [Series.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html), where there is no such concept as *common columns*.