# Pandas replacing values in a column by values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe X (ppid is unique):

```
    ppid  col2 ...
1   'id1'  '1'
2   'id2'  '2'
3   'id3'  '3'
...
```

I have another dataframe which serves as a mapping. ppid is same as above and unique, however it might not contain all X's ppids:

```
    ppid  val
1   'id1' '5'
2   'id2' '6'
```

I would like to use the mapping dataframe to switch col2 in dataframe X according to where the ppids are equal (in reality, they're multiple columns which are unique together), to get:

```
    ppid  col2 ...
1   'id1'  '5'
2   'id2'  '6'
3   'id3'  '3' # didn't change, as there's no match
...
```

Comment: Merge in the second DataFrame on `ppid` with `how='left'`, and use `fillna` to fill in the gaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Jeremy Z answer on this post, for further explanation on solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631906/16235276

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ppid')
df2 = df2.set_index('ppid')
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `map` with `set_index`:

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'ppid':['id1','id2','id3'], 'col2':[*'123']})

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'ppid':['id1','id2'], 'val':[*'56']})

df_x['col2'] = df_x['ppid'].map(df_a.set_index('ppid')['val']).fillna(df_x['col2'])
```

Output:

```
  ppid col2
0  id1    5
1  id2    6
2  id3    3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: `df_x['ppid']` is not a DataFrame, it's a Series. This code works on your sample.

Comment: df_x has more columns in reality, which were omitted for brevity... is it a small fix?

Comment: This doesn't matter.  We are only createing a new column in df_x called 'Col2' All the there colums in df_x stay the same and are not affected.

Answer (score 2):

Input data:

```
>>> dfX
    ppid col1 col2 col3
0  'id1'  'X'  '5'  'A'
1  'id2'  'Y'  '6'  'B'
2  'id3'  'Z'  '3'  'C'

>>> dfM
    ppid  val
0  'id1'  '5'
1  'id2'  '6'
```

`dfX` is your first dataframe and `dfM` is your mapping dataframe:

```
>>> dfM.rename(columns={'val': 'col2'}).combine_first(dfX).loc[:, df.columns]

    ppid col1 col2 col3
0  'id1'  'X'  '5'  'A'
1  'id2'  'Y'  '6'  'B'
2  'id3'  'Z'  '3'  'C'
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you have a problem of column arrangement, have you?

Answer (score 0):

First merge your dataframes then use `pd.Series.combine_first`

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='ppid')
df1['col2'] = df1.val.combine_first(df1.col2)
del df1['val']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ppid': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 'col2': ['1', '2', '3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ppid': ['id1', 'id2'], 'col2': ['5', '6']})

merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ppid')
merged['col2_y'].fillna(merged['col2_x'], inplace=True)

merged
```

```
  ppid col2_x col2_y
0  id1      1      5
1  id2      2      6
2  id3      3      3
```