# how to update an old dataframe from newest one

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

i have this old DataFrame:

| Énergie(keV) | Intensité(%) | Type | Parent | Période | Unité |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.31275 | 2.18 | XL | Fr-221 | 4.79 | min |
| 78.94000 | 0.96 | XKα2 | Fr-221 | 4.79 | min |
| 81.51000 | 1.59 | XKα1 | Fr-221 | 4.79 | min |
| 92.30930 | 0.55 | XKβ1 | Fr-221 | 4.79 | min |

i want update the 3 first columns with;

| Énergie(keV) | Intensité(%) | Type | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.31275 | 18 | γ | Fr-221 |
| 75.94000 | 25 | γ | Fr-221 |
| 89.51000 | 1.09 | XKα1 | Fr-221 |
| 99.00000 | 0.85 | γ | Fr-221 |

I have a big dataframe , but they havn't a same dimensions;

Comment: By what logic should be the two dataframes merged?

Comment: I think something like ```old_df[['col1','col2','col3']] = new_df[['col1','col2','col3']]```

Comment: Hi. Is this what you're looking for? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768657/replace-column-values-based-on-another-dataframe-python-pandas-better-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768657/replace-column-values-based-on-another-dataframe-python-pandas-better-way)

Answer (score 0):

it look like this the old one:
|Énergie(keV)|  Intensité(%)|   Type  | Parent |    Période|    Unité|
|:-----------|:------------:|:-------:|:------:|:---------:|:-------:|
|0.381       |0.019         |XL       |Sc-44   |3.97       |h        |
|10.408      |0.45          |XL       |Ti-44   |60.0       |a        |
|0.430       |0.00013       |XL       |Fr-221  |83.788     |d        |

the forth row mus be updated from the new dataframe