# Assign df columns values based on another df column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 5], 
                    'Name': ['client', 'detail_client', 'operations', audit],
                    'Type': ['str', 'var', 'str', 'nvar']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5, 3, 7, 2], 
                    'Name': ['audit', 'operations', 'C', 'detail_client'],
                    'Type': ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']})
```

I would like to create a function that takes as arguments `df1`, `df2`, `df1['ID']`, `df2['ID']`, `df1['Name']`, `df2['Name']`, `df1['Type']` and `df2['Type']` because columns label may not always identical.
For each row of `df1`. Iterate over `df2`. Compare `df1['ID']` value with `df2['ID']` and `df1['Name']` value with `df2['Name']`. When true. Set `df2['Type']`=`df1['Type']`. The function should return `df2` with `df2['Type']` equal to `df1['Type']` when the condition is true.
I expect `df2` to be like the following `df`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5, 3, 7, 2], 
                    'Name': ['audit', 'operations', 'nan', 'detail_client'],
                    'Type': ['nvar', 'str', 'nan', 'var']})
```

Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two dataframes on `ID` and `Name`:

```py
merged = df2.merge(df1, on=["ID", "Name"], how="left")
mask = merged["Type_y"].notna()
df2.loc[mask, "Type"] = merged.loc[mask, "Type_y"]

print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
   ID           Name  Type
0   5          audit  nvar
1   3     operations   str
2   7              C   nan
3   2  detail_client   var
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function something like this, which borrows its method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631906/9473764):

```
def update_columns(df1, df2, match_cols, merge_cols):
    res = df1.set_index(match_cols)
    res.update(df2.set_index(match_cols)[merge_cols])
    return res.reset_index()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 5], 
                    'Name': ['client', 'detail_client', 'operations', 'audit'],
                    'Type': ['str', 'var', 'str', 'nvar']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [5, 3, 7, 2], 
                    'Name': ['audit', 'operations', 'C', 'detail_client'],
                    'Type': ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']})

out = update_columns(df2, df1, ['ID', 'Name'], ['Type'])
```

Output:

```
   ID           Name  Type
0   5          audit  nvar
1   3     operations   str
2   7              C   nan
3   2  detail_client   var
```